# Cannot make footer responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap 3` with sticky footer feature, I noticed that if I reduce the window to minimum I get the button to right go to ahead.

What I want though is for the footer height to enlarge, so the content doesn't go out to footer.

This is my code:

```
<div id="footer" class="footer">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <h6 class="text-white">Developed by a normal user as you</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" id="select-language" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" rel="select-language" data-original-title="" title="">
            Select a language</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.footer
{
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4790ca;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 3;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

the result that appear is like this:

[image]

[this is a jsfiddle that replicate the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28738/)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the footer gets too small for the button to be on the same line as the text?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `I get the button to right go to ahead, this is my code` - In your fiddle, when running in Chrome, when making the width of the window smaller the button goes below the text not ahead of it. Is that not what you want? What is it you want to happen?

Comment: @BSMP I want the footer height enlarged, so the content doesn't go out to footer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're `float`ing all elements in the `.footer` (`pull-left` and `pull-right`), you need to [apply a clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) on it. [Bootstrap provides a built-in class](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/clearfix/) that you can use.

```
<div id="footer" class="footer clearfix"> ... </div>
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/v9yxefyc/)

[image: Output]

Comment: its actually not declaring the `height` made the footer responsive :) not the clearfix? just I think hehe

Comment: @AgainMe don't judge the book by it's cover buddy, didn't do anything, why should I downvote? I'm not mean, just stating what I found :) relax!

Comment: @AgainMe I downvoted it because the answer is wrong as it is written and does **not** reflect the code which works for different reasons. The answer states `clearfix` was the solution but it is **not**. The reason the linked code works is because John **removed** your `height:50px` - `clearfix` is not needed to fix your issue at all. See  Roljhon's answer, which is not missleading you to think `clearfix` did it

Comment: @Rolijhon I believe you are correct. The `height: auto` (or removing the height) fixes this - and that's because it has `position: absolute`. If the footer weren't positioned absolutely, however, a clearfix would have been needed.

Comment: @JohnBupit yes you're right, I based my answer from the current css anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of your footer to `auto` if you want your button not to go out from the footer

Answer (score -1):

**In media query you need to set**

```
.footer { height: auto; text-align: center; }
```